# How to listen to events in tests in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, laravel-events

I am trying to test emails in laravel 5 and I have realised that `Swift_Mailer` triggers `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` event whenever a mail is being sent.

But since I am beginner, I am having trouble comprehending how to listen to this event and take out the underlying message object?

I have tried this but I don't this is correct:

```
public function test_the_email_via_listening_to_message_sending_event()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    Event::fire(new UserWasCreated($user));

    Event::listen(Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending::class, function($message){
        echo 'Hello';
    });
}
```

How to listen to a particular event in a test case and trigger code in response to it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#mocking-events

Comment: Left a comment on the answer regarding the same

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides an `expectsEvents` method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#mocking-events

```
$this->expectsEvents(Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending::class);
```

Comment: I am not trying to mock events. In fact I am trying to do high level functional testing where I am trying to catch the emails before they are sent and assert that the subject, body and so on are in a certain way. Which is why I am looking for a way to trap the email before it is sent and perform assertions on it.

Comment: @Rohan In that case, you might do best checking Laravel's own tests for the Mail functionality. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/tests/Mail/MailMessageTest.php